# EmberJS Event when record is deleted

Tags: javascript, events, ember.js

Is there an event in EmberJS I can register to be notified when a record is deleted?

I tried `record.on('isDeleted', ...)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: How is the record being deleted? This is the standard method of handling a record deletion. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/#toc_deleting-records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`didDelete` event](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.Model/events?anchor=) is fired when the record is deleted.